# Back Button enabled deep-linking in IE

Tags: javascript, html

This is a problem that SWFAddress have fixed. But essentially, I'd like to write my own solution that strips out a lot of unused functions.  Explanation below:

You can use the following code to get the hash value of the an URL link like this xxx.xxx.com/?#/DeepLinking/

```
window.location.hash
```

Using anchor tags with `href='#tab1`...etc. and Javascript, you can make deep linking work. Whenever the hash changes, I can serve the user different content.

The problem comes up when you use the back button and the `window.location.hash`. In other browsers other than IE, if you use the back button to go back to a previous hash symbol state, the `window.location.hash` returns the correct value. In IE, it does not return the current hash value but the one before any Back button was pressed.

I saw an Iframe fix but I'm not sure how exactly it works? Please provide a framework agnostic solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a look at the [**YUI 2: Browser History Manager**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/). Browse through its sources to look how they did it.

EDIT: Or have a look at [**history.js**](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/history/history.js) from Google's Closure Library.

Answer (score 0):

Check out History.js http://github.com/browserstate/history.js - it's framework agnostic and designed for the newer HTML5 History API which allows you to modify the url directly, so you don't incur [the issues of hashes](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling).